# Определение GPS координат

Tags: android, gps

Посоветуйте, какую-нибудь статью грамотную почитать и/или пример по определению GPS-координат?

Comment: > какую-нибудь статью грамотную почитать

Легко. Почитайте документацию.

> пример по определению GPS-координат

И это можно. Загляните в документацию. Там всё есть.

Comment: а попроще можно? )

Comment: Гм. Попроще чем в документации? Куда уж проще то?

Comment: Ок, я погуглил за вас, [держите][1].

  [1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=android+get+gps+coordinates

Answer (score 2):

Если лень разбираться, возьмите [little-fluffy-location-library](https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/)